# get row and column names of n maximum values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

For the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2],'col2':[4,5]},index=['row1','row2'])
print df
      col1  col2
row1     1     4
row2     2     5
```

I want to get the row name and the col name of the 2 maximum values and the according maximum values, such that the resulting expression returns something like this:

```
[(row1,col2,4)(row2,col2,5)]
```

Whats the most concise way to do that in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for creating `Series`, then [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and last create `tuples` by list comprehension:

```
print (df)
      col1  col2
row1     1     4
row2     2     5

df1 = df.stack().nlargest(2).reset_index()
print (df1)
  level_0 level_1  0
0    row2    col2  5
1    row1    col2  4

tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df1.values]
print (tuples)
[('row2', 'col2', 5), ('row1', 'col2', 4)]
```

Comment: Glad can help you!